# have been proposing and leading

Tags: grammaticality

> I have been proposing and leading the projects such as Project A and
>   Project B in the company.

Is "have been proposing and leading" grammatical?
Assume I have already proposed, and I am currently leading.

Comment: Can you you tell us why you think the sentence might not be grammatical?

Answer (score -1):

I find that *the projects such as* is inherently ungrammatical, because the use of *the* means that the projects in question have already been mentioned.

I would say that omitting *the* is correct:

> I have been proposing and leading projects such as Project A and Project B in the company.

As for whether *have been proposing and leading* is grammatical or not, it looks fine to me. I suspect that your question arises from having one modal verb and two participles. If so, that's perfectly ok, and very common.  Consider this:

> They have been laughing and talking together for three hours now.

You don't need to say

> They have been laughing and have been talking together for three hours now.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter can explain why he/she feels this is a bad answer, so I can improve my future efforts.